# FoundationDB RAM requirements

Tags: foundationdb

According to the website FoundationDB requires 4GB

https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/configuration.html#system-requirements

Can someone explain why it needs so much and what would happen if I only have 1 GB with SSD mode?

Also wouldn't the requirements depend if I am using SSD or Memory Mode?

Answer (score 1):

The same question has been discussed [here](https://forums.foundationdb.org/t/foundationdb-ram-requirements/1646). Posting the relevant answers

> I think we’ve meant to change the 4GB to 8GB, as that’s the bar that
>   most knobs have been configured to meet, and how most folk are running
>   it in production. And that’s what this guidance is meant for. The
>   default settings of FDB are such that in most reasonable uses, FDB
>   won’t run out of memory and die even if you subject it to a high
>   degree of load if you have 8GB of memory per fdbserver process.
>
> FDB isn’t meant to be a low memory usage database. It’s generally hard
>   to acquire CPU and disk without also acquiring memory, and if the
>   memory is available, then it’s better to use it than leave it unused.
>   8GB per core/disk is a sort of reasonable guess at the average ratios
>   in a server. There’s various components that are (by default) happy to
>   hold 1-2GB of data in memory. Notably, this is transaction logs
>   holding the most recent N seconds of mutations in memory, or storage
>   servers keeping a ~2GB page cache.
>
> If you only have 1GB with SSD mode, then because the page cache
>   defaults to 2GB, you’ll OOM as soon as your total data volume is >1GB,
>   and you read all of it once. The memory storage engine has its own
>   limits, which you can adjust with --storage_memory.

Another answer

> I don’t remember all the history here, but it’s possible the 4GB
>   requirement was meant to represent a rough idea of what you might need
>   to install the packages on a machine and run some simple workloads
>   against the resulting cluster. I don’t think it’s required to have the
>   full 8GB for simple cases like that. For production, though, I agree
>   that the listed requirement should probably be higher.